# Correctly use Kivy Canvas in Python

Tags: python-3.x, canvas, kivy

Assuming I define a `BoxLayout` but want to add, say a blue background to it, in Kivy it would look something like this:

```
BoxLayout:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: 0, 0, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
```

I tried to do this in Python like this:

```
box = BoxLayout()
with box.canvas.before:
    Color(rgb=(0, 0, 1))
    Rectangle(size=box.size, pos=box.pos)
```

This does draw a rectangle, but not in the correct size or position. My question is: is there a way to create a `Rectangle` (or another way to add a background to a `BoxLayout`) the same size and position of the defined `BoxLayout`? The closest I have ever gotten is physically setting the size and shape, but I would like this `Rectangle` to be dynamically resizable so that I don't have too many values hard-coded. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, that code would appear in some method of a class, so a reference to the `Rectangle` could be saved as, for example, `self.bg`.  So it would like something like this:

```
class MyBackground(FloatLayout):
     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyBackground, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.box = BoxLayout(size_hint=(0.5, 0.5))
        with self.box.canvas.before:
            Color(rgba=(1, 0, 0, 1))
            self.bg = Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)

        # bindings to keep size and position of the Rectangle up to date
        self.box.bind(pos=self.update_bg)
        self.box.bind(size=self.update_bg)

        # add box to this layout
        self.add_widget(self.box)

     def update_bg(self, *args):
         self.bg.pos = self.box.pos
         self.bg.size = self.box.size
```

Comment: This worked for me, but why do we have to do it in this way?

Comment: The line of python code: `Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)` sets the size and position of the Rectangle to the size and position of  of the BoxLayout at the time the code is executed. That pos and size are (0,0) and (100,100), the defaults, at that time. And there is no automatic binding to adjust the Rectangle when the pos and size of the BoxLayout change, so you must create those bindings. The kivy language, however, does create those bindings automatically for you.